# rsync won't sync with at symbol (@) in path

Tags: rsync, escape-characters, special-characters, character-special-files

I'm trying to rsync a folder on a remote server (Synology) to my server (TrueNAS), but the path has the at/email symbol (@) in it and I think rsync is throwing an error (below) because it's confused as to how to read that. I tried , \, /, // to escape the @ symbol and single & double quotes around the whole remote path and then just around the path after the colon, but I get the same error every time. Any ideas?

```
$ rsync -avrth --progress john@10.0.0.11:"/volume1/documents/john/onedrive - johndoe@server.com/" /mnt/tank/home/john/

receiving incremental file list
rsync: link_stat "/volume1/documents/john/onedrive" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/volume1/homes/john/-" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/volume1/homes/john//johdoe@server.com" failed: No such file or directory (2)

sent 8 bytes  received 302 bytes  36.47 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1673) [Receiver=3.1.3]
rsync: [Receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)
```

Comment: I think it is the source name (with spaces in it) that is causing problems, rather than the target with the @ in it.

Comment: Thank you @Haxiel ! Adding "--protect-args" to the rsync options did the job. Rsync is now syncing with the @ symbol in the path name.